# How to paint pandas scatter matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, plot

[Pandas scatter matrix](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#scatter-matrix-plot) - is an instrument for plotting paired features. For example we have famous data set with Irises. Scatter matrix in this case looks something like this:

[image]

How can I paint Iris Setosa in yellow, Virginica in blue and Versicolour in red?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a color vector via the `c` parameter

```
iris = datasets.load_iris()
df=pd.DataFrame(iris.data)
colMap={0:"red",1:"blue",2:"yellow"}
cols=list(map(lambda x:colMap.get(x),iris.target))
scatter_matrix(df,  diagonal='hist',c=cols)
```